# Typing Tamil using XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex

I tried to use the given example with slight modification

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}

\newfontfamily\tamilfont{Arial Unicode MS}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{tamil}

\begin{document}

அ 

தொலைந்தது 

தமிழ்

\end{document}
```

Though அ and தமிழ் rendered correctly, தொலைந்தது came very bad.
Will you point out the error.

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome, i just tested with some random font i found on the internet, `latha.ttf`, and the output looks fine. Can you check with a different font? If this is a bug in the font, the maintainers should be informed.

Comment: I tried various fonts.\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Georgia}
\newfontfamily{\maintext}{Georgia}
\newfontfamily{\lathatamil}{Latha}
\newfontfamily{\aksartamil}{Akshar Unicode}
\newfontfamily{\chemtamil}{Chemmozhi Thendral}
\newfontfamily{\sundtamil}{Uni Ila.Sundaram-01}

\begin{document}

 I typed
 
 {\lathatamil கொடியது } 
  
{\aksartamil  கொடியது }

{\sundtamil கொடியது }

{\chemtamil கொடியது }

\end{document}

Comment: Can you edit that to the question? Code markup in comments is a mess, and by editing, your question will be placed on top of the list, making it visible to others.

Comment: @ArivarignanGunaseelan I got same bad result as you with LuaLaTeX, but using XeLaTeX, the output seems to be correct

Comment: @michal.h21 and @Johannes . I was able to resolve my problem. I added  ` [Script=Tamil] ' option in ` \newfontfamily\tamilfont[Script=Tamil]{Arial Unicode MS} '. Now it works fine. Thanks.

Comment: @ArivarignanGunaseelan you can post it as answer to your question, so it can be marked as solved